# How to return Video size when the video is auto resized by browser

Tags: javascript, css, video

I'm trying to have a video scaled to the entire size of my page, without any vertical or horizontal bars.

Since my client uses IE I can't use this:

```
object-fit: fill;
```

In order to manually scale the video to the page I need to be able to read the size of the displayed video (Not the size of the video's metadata) so that I can later scale it using CSS Transform

This is how the video gets displayed on my page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WioBT.png

How do I go about reading these values?

Thanks a bunch you guys save lives :)

Comment: Just to make it a bit clearer, I want to return the values of 1392 and 783

Comment: The video itself is 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

The GlobalEventHandlers.onresize property contains an EventHandler triggered when a resize event is received.

```
function resize() { 
   let _height = window.innerHeight; // Window height
   let _width = window.innerWidth; // Window width
}

window.onresize = resize;
```

You can for example get your video height with

```
let videoHeight = document.getElementById('myVideo').videoHeight
let videoWidth = document.getElementById('myVideo').videoWidth
```

Comment: Heya, thank you for the answer. The code suggested returns the size of the window/page. What I am trying to find is the size of the video displayed

Comment: Unfortunately this is still returning the size of the page, for example, it is returning 1600, but the actual displayed video size is 1392... The video itself is placed in a container which is 100% scaled vertically and horizontally but is later automatically resized to "fit"

Comment: `videoHeight.videoHeight; // returns the intrinsic height of the video
videoWidth.videoWidth; // returns the intrinsic width of the video`

Comment: Works very nicely if we're trying to get the native size of the video (1920 x 1080)... Here I am attempting to get the size of the video once it has been resized to the page (1392 x 783) - Worth noting I am not doing the resizing, the browser is